# Do I need synchronous calls / transactions using mongodb from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm currently experimenting with node.js and WebSocket, building a simple MMO server and client (nothing complex, just to learn node.js and HTML5). Basic functionality is complete except data persistence. So far, all data has been kept in memory, but now I would like to add persistent storage with mongodb (or something similar). My question is about how to realize the communication between the node.js application and the data base.

The main activity of the server can be described as follows:

receive incoming message (via WebSocket)
-->

1. read data from DB
2. computation on data from step 1
3. read more data from DB (data required depends on outcome of step 2)
4. computation on data from steps 1 and 3
5. write data to DB (create or update)

-->
send response message (via WebSocket)

(steps 3-5 do not always occur)

I guess this is a very common use case.

Questions:

1. Since the data read in steps 1 and 3 must be consistent AND the write in step 5 might no longer be valid if data in DB has changed between steps 3 and 5, it seems to me that I cannot use async calls to the DB at all (because then data in the DB might be changed by other code in between the above steps). Is that correct?
2. When thinking of a deployment with multiple instances of node.js working on the same DB (I think this is what nodejitsu calls "drones", right?) then I even have to use data base transactions spanning steps 1 through 5. Is that correct?

It seems to me that using synchronous calls to the DB and having transactions in all these cases would be poor design and introduce performance issues. Is there a better way to do this?

Any hints would be greatly appreaciated! Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:**

node.js is asynchronous. That is a fact. If you are not able to design your app under this pattern, you cannot use node.js

Of course, there are techniques and patterns, that allow you to do what you want within an asynchronous environment. Here are some keywords, functions, and links that might lead you to the right direction:

- Queueing
- [Optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)
- [mongoDB/findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)
- [redis/transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)

**Question 2:**

It might be nice to use transactions, but you cannot, because [mongoDB does not have any](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-support-transactions). You have to program them yourself nodejs-side. That`s one of the mongoDB fundamentals: All power to the programmer (and not the database). Weal and woe!

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback, very helpful! After looking into the info you have referenced and reading some related documentation, it seems to me that if I want to keep the logic in steps 2 and 4 simple and flexible and independent of the structure of the data in the data base (something like scripts that can be changed/extended by users), there is probably no way around transactions or something similar. In any case, this is all very interesting :-)